# Does the error mean this file was not created using OpenSSL? If not, how do I figure out what encrypted this file?

Tags: openssl, file-types

When running the below command, I received this error:

```
OpenSSL> rsautl -decrypt -in binarytext -out file.txt -inkey file2.txt
unable to load Private Key
7324:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
error in rsautl
```

Does anyone know how to figure out what encryption was used with the beginning looking like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. How did you generate the pictures? Which one is which file? Try to reduce your question to a single question. As it stands, you have many. I'll try to answer them but it is really helpful to simplify your question.

Comment: Many kinds of computer data, including many kinds of cryptographic data, are 'binary' -- they don't consist of characters, and trying to look at them visually or post them destroys most of the content and is useless. Use `od -tx1` or `xxd` or `hexdump` to get a hex dump and post the first few lines (say 4) of your key file, which should be enough to understand the format without compromising your private key, and the _exact_ size of your data file.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?                                                                                       0C 17 FF 40 51 88 FC E4 74 D5 90 89 60 93 31 CC          . . ÿ@QˆüätÕ . ‰`“1Ì                                             
3C B0 F9 EB 51 3F 51 A0 7A 28 41 FB 95 9E 15 58          <°ùëQ?Q z(Aû•ž . X                                            91 C2 67 C1 80 16 71 52 5F 2A 02 96 8B 18 8E E3           ‘ÂgÁ€ .qR_* . –‹ . Žã                                          74 6A F5 31 36 14 F0 BF C6 7B CD B8 4B F6 65 3F         tjõ16 . ð¿Æ{Í¸Köe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer your questions, and other implied ones.

**Q: Does the error mean this file was not created using OpenSSL?**
A: No.

**Q: If not, how do I figure out what encrypted this file?**
A: You probably will not be able to, possibly by design of the encryption.

**Q Implied: Even if it was not encrypted by OpenSSL, can it possibly still decrypt it?**
A: Absolutely. OpenSSL is a general purpose enc/dec tool. It works with most, if not all, standard encryption formats and techniques.

**Q: Does anyone recognize this encryption format?**
A: Unless there is a standard header that someone recognizes, which as I understand it is uncommon, unlikely.

**Q Implied: What does this error mean?**
A: "`unable to load Private Key`" means OpenSSL was not able to load the key you told it to load. The following lines describe the error in more detail.